# How to access local mysql from chrome packages app

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am developing a chrome packaged app. There is already an VB application running with mysql. I want to access the same database but use chrome packaged app as client.

How to access local mysql server from chrome packages app using javascript ?

I am aware of IndexedDB.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Create a web service (e.g. some PHP pages) that talks to MySQL and allows your app to use it as a go-between
2. Write your own MySQL driver/communicator to communicate with it directly: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html

The first is the easiest and would take the form:

1. Your chrome app would use AJAX to communicate with the PHP pages (probably via "POST")
2. Your PHP pages would expect it to login, use SSL and then use a token to continue identification during a session
3. The PHP would have generic capabilities to do CRUD actions
4. The PHP would spit back JSON for the results

*but* the second option would make you a hero if you took the time to develop that and put it on sourceforge or github under a permissive open source license.

Comment: As the mysql is running in the local desktop which maynot be connected to internet, I have to go with second option. I am trying to use chrome UI for desktop application. I will try using socket, otherwise I will go with [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/) for developing the desktop application.

Comment: even if not connected to internet, the first option would still work. just run a web server on the same computer.

Comment: ..that is only open to localhost IP

Comment: @J.Krishna Did you ever implement this? Did you open source it online?

Comment: @DonRhummy I am using node-webkit / electron (atom.io) to do the same.

Comment: @J.Krishna Would you mind putting the code for doing that on github? (and link it here?) It would help a lot of people